# How can I make the spell checker work in MS Word on iPad?

Tags: ipad, ms-office

On my iPad, the Word spellchecker does not work. "Proofing Language" is grayed out and cannot be selected. See screenshot.

I have already searched the internet for a long time for a solution and tried a lot for months, but it does not work.

The spell checker worked temporarily in different Word documents, „Proofing Language“ was no longer grayed out and could be selected. However, after about one hour, it was grayed out again and the spell checker is currently not working.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a MS365 subscription?

Comment: Yes, I have a MS365 subscription and I‘m logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After months of not working, today, the spell checker temporarily worked. I did not change anything. It just started to work.

After about an hour, it stopped working again.

I then uninstalled Word, re-installed it, and now spell-checking works —- for now.

It may have something todo with the language „German (Switzerland)“.